# What's the difference between a cathedral and a basilica?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

The references I've seen so far have alternated primacy between one and the other.

Comment: There is no need to capitalize unless you are referring to a specific building.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A **basilica** was originally, in Hellenistic Greece,  a tribunal administering justice on behalf of the king (βασιλέως - basileus). The word and the thing were adopted by the Romans after annexing Macedonia in the 2<sup>nd</sup> Century BC.  The archeological site of Pompeii, for instance, has the [remains of a large basilica](http://www.vitruvius.be/pompei.htm) which served as a tribunal, and a few hundred meters away in the modern city of Pompeii a [catholic basilica](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santuario_della_Beata_Vergine_del_Rosario_di_Pompei).

When [Constantine officially legalised the Christian faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantine_the_Great_and_Christianity) ([Edict of Milan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edict_of_Milan)) as one of the Empire’s state religions (4<sup>th</sup> century A.D.)<sup>1</sup>, he erected a number of large churches which were then named basilicas.  The current [Basilica of St Peter’s in Rome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Peter's_Basilica) replaces a previous building built precisely by Constantine.  As a general rule basilicas are the highest ranking churches and are declared so by the Pope.  Some high profile basilicas are built on top of the burials of notable saints (St Peter's, St Francesco of Assisi, St Vasily in Moscow, St Paul Outside the Walls...)

---

**Cathedrals**, on the other hand, were typically built during the Middle Ages. They are headed by a bishop.  However, if this bishop is head of his diocese, then his cathedral outranks any basilica in his diocese.

Neither cathedrals nor basilicas are restricted to the Catholic faith: see [St. Basil's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Basil%27s_Cathedral) in Moscow, of the Russian Orthodox Church (remarkably sometimes translated as *basilica*; sometimes to *cathedral*).

<sup>1</sup> He also decided we would rest on Sundays ;-)

Comment: Thanks, the outranking thing is probably why I see them given different emphasis.

Comment: @SriAtluru. I fail to understand how you "differ" from my statement "As a general rule basilicas are the highest ranking churches and are declared so by the Pope."  Plese also consider this [authoritative source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica#Ranking_of_churches): *"The papal or major basilicas outrank in precedence all other churches. Other rankings put the cathedral (or co-cathedral) of a bishop ahead of all other churches in the same diocese, even if they have the title of basilica."*.

Comment: Yeah. My bad. Wrong interpretation. Sorry.

Comment: @Sri Atluru. No prob. You had me read that very interesting wikipedia articles about [St Louis Basilica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathedral_Basilica_of_St._Louis).  I had no idea it had been designated a basilica by John-Paul II. Cheers.   Coincidently there is another St Louis Cathedral close to where I live at the moment in Tunis.  I don't think it has St Louis tomb though, although he surely died here in 1270 AD.

Comment: You should see the basilica at St. Louis. It is really really beautiful. One of the few places where the moment you go in, you feel you are in the midst of something awesome.When I told about it to my grandpa, he said they were larger and more beautiful basilicas in europe, especially in Italy and France. Visiting the basilica in Lourdes is on my to-do list. We used to have a small statue of Mary, which was made in Lourdes, in our prayer room back in India.

Comment: Just a minor correction. Constantine did not make Christianity the official state religion. He did make it a legal religion and directed to establish a single doctrine. It was not until the emperor Theodosius I that the church was made the official as sole state religion in 380 a.d.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @sumelic, Duly amended, Many Thanks.  Please note however that towards the end of his reign, [Constantine had turned officially against paganism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-paganism_policy_of_Constantine_I).

Answer (score 10):

A cathedral is the proper term a church that is home to a bishop. A basilica may refer to anything from a church's architecture to its importance to the pope, depending on its type. The Holy Roman Catholic Church categorizes basilica according to their function: palace, a papal seat of authority, etc. Some cathedrals are also called basilica, but it's generally the case that a basilica outranks a cathedral in matters of church authority.

Comment: Throw in "minster" for more confusion. I think "cathedral" is the only one of the three that has a single unambiguous definition. A "cathedral church" is a a church that contains a "cathedra", or Bishop's seat.

Comment: Minister is just anglo-saxon for cathedral

Comment: @Martin Becket - see http://www.yorkminster.org/general/faqs/ for their definition of minster.  Wikipedia doesn't seem to totally agree.

Comment: @neil - true, I should have said major church - although I can't think of a minster that isn't (or wasn't) a cathedral

Answer (score 5):

A cathedral is the principal church of a diocese, while *basilica* is the name given to certain churches granted special privileges by the pope.

Answer (score 3):

A cathedra (Latin, "chair", from Greek, kathedra, "seat") or bishop's throne is the chair or throne of a bishop.

Comment: And 'cathedral' is the adjective: *cathedral church* was shortened to *cathedral*